# Determination of sample size for a Kendall's tau correlation, one variable ordinal and the other continuous

Tags: correlation, sample-size, ordinal-data, continuous-data, kendall-tau

I'm a bit stuck at the moment. I have a study where we are comparing a new method of strength measurement that will give output in lbs of force versus the standard methos of grading it on a 0-5 ordinal scale (by subjective measurement). Given that there will be many tied ranks I would presume Kendall's tau would be more appropriate than Spearman rank correlation.

There was a similar study performed and they simply used linear regression for their sample size, but I'm at a loss as to how to determine the sample size in my case. I believe they simply used linear regression as it was more simple, but likely was not the appropriate method. However I do have some expected means for the categories of 0-5 and their standard deviations as a result. I also am interested if a bland-altman approach can be considered.

Thank you for your response, I really appreciate any help.

I've read this article, but it is more advanced tham I'm able to work with mathematically. "https://www.researchgate.net/publication/279926406_Sample_size_requirements_for_estimating_Pearson_Kendall_and_Spearman_correlations"